# How to make a popup box above link with items to choose from?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I have jQuery to show/hide a div of emotiocons whenever a user clicks on 'Emoticons'.

What I like to do is to have a small box containing emoticon items to popup above the link, instead of a div being opened below it (Just as what we see in common WYSIWYG editors)

Here is what I already have:

file.html

```
      <a href="#" id="showhide_emobox"> Emoticons </a>
        <div id="emobox">
            <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":)" />
            <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":(" />
            <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":D" />
        </div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('#showhide_emobox').click(function(){
    $('#emobox').toggle();
    });
```

I'm very new to front end development and not sure how to achieve this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base of this is use a Wrapper for the a tag and the div with the emoticons, then use `absolute` position and display `none` to get the desire effect

```js
$('#showhide_emobox').click(function() {
  $('#emobox').fadeToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.em {
  margin-top:100px;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
  text-align:center;
}
.em a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  font-family:'verdana';
  line-height:50px;
  border-radius:10px;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
.em a:hover,.em a.active {
  background:orange;
}
#emobox {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#emobox input {
  displa:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="em">
  <a href="#" id="showhide_emobox"> Emoticons </a>
  <div id="emobox">
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":)" />
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":(" />
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":D" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @hbsd I don't think that can be a problem, have you any errors in the console?

Comment: Well, 'em' apparently already been used in bootstrap css :), when I changed it to 'emo' the code works fine. However, I'd like to have 'emoticon' to be wrapped in a box. Can you modify your code for this too please?

Comment: You already have what you wanted @hbsd this is a good source to guid you, if you want a box just modify the input style or wrap it on a div each one :)

Comment: Cheers Danko. you saved my day.

Comment: @hbsd glad to help U :)

Answer (score 0):

this may require some javascript to properly do this (with position absolute, overlaying boxes), but as a simple answer to this, change your html to:

```
<div>
    <div id="emobox">
        <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":)" />
        <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":(" />
        <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":D" />
    </div>     
    <a href="#" id="showhide_emobox"> Emoticons </a>
</div>
```

Comment: well, what I want is a popup box, not another div that just come above the link.

Answer (score 0):

this the basic

```js
    function active () {
      this.classList.toggle("active")
    }

    var anchor = document.querySelector("a");

    anchor.addEventListener("click", active, false);
```

```css
    *{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}
    :root{
      padding-top: 150px;
      text-align: center
    }
    a{
      position: relative;
    }
    [id=emobox]{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 0;
      display: none;
      width: 132px;
      margin-left: -50%;
      background: rgb(116, 50, 187);
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    a.active [id=emobox]{
      display: block;   
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" id=showhide_emobox>
  <span>Emoticons</span>
  <div id=emobox>
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":)" />
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":(" />
    <input class="emoticon" type="button" value=":D" />
  </div> 
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but this not quite what I wanted. I want a box that appear on click and contain the elements.

Comment: Great. Just need the emticons to be wrapped in a nice box. Please add that and I'll accpet your answer as the css is more elegant.

Comment: Sorry Tambo I just tried the code and it does not work on my page. So have to accept other answer. really appreciate your help anyway.